# AFNetworking placeholderImage animating?(animating while downloading)

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, afnetworking

There are apps which show animating images(opposed to a static image) while downloading an image asynchronously.

Pinterest is one for example.

I wonder if this is possible with AFNetworking? or are there other libraries to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `AFNetworking` is only a library for easily allow developer te grab data from the web I don't tink it will do any animation.

You could use `AFNetworking` to get the image from the web and write your own animation code that gets displayed when the image is downloaded. The eastiest way is to use `UIView` animations.